# ggplot2/ barplot/ get bars closer / adjusting "width" doesn't work

Tags: r

Please help get two bars closer. I've played with "width" functions in `geom_bar` and `position_dodge` all day long now with no success. Thanks in advance.

My data:

```
race  rate
1     11.860087
2     8.894954
```

My code:

```
ggplot(visrate, aes(factor(race), rate, fill=race, label=sprintf("%0.1f", round(rate, digits = 1)))) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.25, position = position_dodge(width = 0.01)) +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1") +
    scale_fill_discrete(name="Race", breaks=c("1", "2"),labels=c("Caucasian", "African-American")) +
    scale_y_continuous(name = "Pancreatic Cancer Hospitalization Rate, 1995-2013",limits = c(0, 12),breaks = seq(0, 12, by = 2)) +
    ggtitle("Pancreatic Cancer Hospitalizations by Race") +
    theme(text=element_text(size = 10, family="courier")) +
    geom_text(size = 4, hjust = 0.5, vjust=1.5) + 
    theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
```

[image: Barplot]

Comment: set `width = 1` in `geom_bar()` to remove any space between the bars. Is that what you wanted? You have two `scale_fill_xxx` - you can only have one, and race should be as a factor both times in the `aes`

Comment: Richard, thanks, yes, no space between my bars now, great!!!, but became very fat ones, any idea to narrow them?

Comment: Just shrink the width of the plot window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a dodged plot - position dodging is used when you have multiple bars *at the same x-axis position*. Here, you have two x-axis values and two bars, no need for dodge.

Inside `geom_bar`, `width` refers to what percentage of the space between the bars is "full of bar". You have `width = 0.25`, so the bars take up 25% of the space. If you want the bars to touch set `width = 1`. If you want them to almost touch use `width = 0.9`.

Also, as pointed out in the comments, only one `scale_fill` will be used on a plot. If you add two, the first one will be ignored. And you should be consistent in using `race` as a factor (best would be to change it beforehand in the data frame).

```
ggplot(visrate, aes(factor(race), rate, fill = factor(race), label=sprintf("%0.1f", round(rate, digits = 1)))) +
    geom_bar(stat= "identity", width = 1) +
    scale_fill_discrete(name="Race", breaks=c("1", "2"),labels=c("Caucasian", "African-American")) +
    scale_y_continuous(name = "Pancreatic Cancer Hospitalization Rate, 1995-2013", limits = c(0, 12), breaks = seq(0, 12, by = 2)) +
    ggtitle("Pancreatic Cancer Hospitalizations by Race") +
    theme(text=element_text(size = 10, family="courier")) +
    geom_text(size = 4, hjust = 0.5, vjust=1.5) + 
    theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
```

Comment: Hi Gregor, Thanks much!!! I still haven't dealt with error saying: "another scale for 'fill', which will replace the existing scale". Is previous "fill" call is "fill = factor(race)"? Once you mentioned fill function here hope I can ask it in the comment here. In addition to existing "fill' options I also want to bring in "scale_fill_brewer()". Do you know how I can bring it in without crashing on the previous scale_fills?